# how to transfer a strings from activiy with each other and show in a listview?

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, android-intent

this is my code

I want to make sure that when you press a button in activity A, the application copies the strings and show in a listview in activity B

how can I do this?

Activity A

```
public class GruppiPuntateActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

ArrayList<String> bottone;
Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gruppipuntate_activity);

   /* //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //rimozione action bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        getSupportActionBar().hide();*/

        b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button8);
        b9 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button9);
        b10 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button10);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
        b10.setOnClickListener(this);

 }
    //gestione Switch java per selezione puntate
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] Product;

        Intent episodi = new Intent(GruppiPuntateActivity.this, EpisodiActivity.class);

         switch(v.getId()){ 
         case R.id.button1:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
         case R.id.button2:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
         case R.id.button3:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
         case R.id.button4:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button5:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button6:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button7:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button8:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button9:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         case R.id.button10:
             Product = new String[]{"primo", "secondo", "terzo"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", Product);
             startActivity(episodi);
              break;
         }
    }
```

ACTIVITY B
    public class EpisodiActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);

    /*//creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //rimozione action bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); 

    }*/
    final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    int[] PP = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("Product"); 
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PP);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);




}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity A is already perfectly fine to pass your String array but in your Activity B you should write

```
String[] PP = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product");
```

instead of

```
int[] PP = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("Product");
```

Comment: Accepting the answer :D

Comment: could you help me to another thing? I'll tell you I want to add this method mylist.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
     public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
     if (position == 1) 
     {
     MyIntent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), EpisodiActivity.class); 
     startActivity (new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ("URL"))); However, if I plug it in Activity B I click any button in Activity A I will come out the same URL as I can change depending on the button clicked?

Comment: you should probably add this as another question so more details can be seen

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an intent, you can attach extras to it for when your other activity receives it. `episodi.putExtra(key, value);` where Key is a string ID for the data, and value is a the data itself (as a string). 
Then in your other activity where the intent is received you can obtain the extras by calling `getIntent().getExtra(key)` for the key you previous used.

Comment: sorry but I'm a noob would you show me with a few lines of co

Comment: Inside EpisodiActivity:
String[] product = getIntent().getExtra("Product");